# docker compose/build ERROR [event_processor base 3/8] RUN /setup.sh

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to set up my docker compose/build but I get a error message I can't find the solution for:
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /setup.sh]: exit code: 100

I also found this:
11.58  installed python3.11-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
11.58 Errors were encountered while processing:
11.58  python3.11-minimal
11.61 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I'm using linux ubuntu if that is something that can affect the issue.

Comment: Show us your dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just downgrade my php-version from 8.2 to 8.1 through my composer.json and then re-runned the build.